# Creating folder with random name and moving files to it

Tags: shell, terminal

I'm working with Hazel at the moment and running some basic shell commands.

At the moment when I drag an image into my chosen folder it creates a folder named by a random 20 digit unique string and adds the file to this folder. This is perfect.

The problem I have is that when I add multiple files to the folder I want to create only one random string folder and all the dragged files to be added to that one new folder.

Currently for every image added to the folder, a new random string folder is created and the image is moved there.

My Shell code is below:

```
randomstring=$(cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc 'a-zA-Z0-9' | fold -w 20 | head -n 1)
mkdir -p $randomstring 
mv $1 $randomstring
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: I can;t tell how the script is invoked. When invoked with all files as parameters, try `mv $* $randomstring`. When it is called many times, you must store the name of the subdir somewhere (or can you find it with something like `find . -type d`) ?

Comment: @StevenMorton If you want to move every argument file to the new *$randomstring* folder, simply run `mv "$@" $randomstring/`. Other than that, you WILL have to keep the name of the folder -- given it's been randomly generate, i.e., you wouldn't except running the script twice and getting the same random name.

Comment: Hazel runs a script on all files in the folder with extension .bmp. This is why it runs the script and each file is in it's own directory. I'd like to run a script on the directory that creates a sub-folder and adds anything that is .bmp to a folder with a unique character name. In this case $1 is used to refer to the file the script is running on.

Comment: @Rubens thanks but that still produces the same error. When I run the preset Hazel command to sort .bmp files into a folder named after the date created this works perfectly as the obviously share the same value. This is exactly what I need to mirror for the unique string folder and addition.

Answer (score 0):

> … I want to create only one random string folder and all the dragged
>   files to be added to that one new folder.

If you have no other 20-character-name folders there, it suffices to prepend a test to check whether such a folder already exists:

```
randomstring=????????????????????/  # 20 question marks, 1 slash (folders)
set -e                              # exit on error to be on the safe side
[ -d $randomstring ] ||             # do next line unless directory exists
randomstring=$(cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc 'a-zA-Z0-9' | fold -w 20 | head -n 1)
mkdir -p $randomstring 
mv $1 $randomstring
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you can related by [KEV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13400312/linux-create-random-directory-file-hierarchy) note make random name for Folder use of following command

---

> mkdir -p {a,b}/{e,f,g}/{h,i,j}

that you can use the SPACE character by ' ' and range of alphabet by using {a..z} in term of above

for example

> mkdir -p {a,b}/{e,{a..z}' '{a..z},g}/{h,i,j}