# What is the reson my expansion is not working

Tags: bash

I have [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13400312/linux-create-random-directory-file-hierarchy) code to generate a random directory structure given some parameters, and a running against the eval limits, so I am trying to use Xargs to work around as per @TheOtherGuy but I am doing something wrong.

```
DIRCMD="mkdir -p $OUTDIR/\"$FLDIR\"/$FLCHILDREN"
```

In VS CODE watch

```
declare -- DIRCMD="mkdir -p ./rndpath/\"LUl\"/{\"KYh\",\"NQ \",\"NU\",\"Hjn\",\"lS\",\"TEW\"}/{\"Rbf\",\"DU\",\"N4\",\"Da7o\",\"aNK\",\"2oS\"}"
```

And do

```
eval "$DIRCMD"
```

Everything works unless I hit the eval expansion limits.

As Per @ThatOtherGuy trying to work around the limitation I tried

```
dircmd1="printf "%s\0 " $OUTDIR/\"$FLDIR\"/$FLCHILDREN"
and 
eval "$dircmd1" | xargs -0 mkdir -p

[admin@119 rndpath]$ tree -a --dirsfirst -s ./
./
└── [       4096]  LUl
    └── [       4096]  {KYh,NQ,NU,Hjn,lS,TEW}
        └── [       4096]  {Rbf,DU,N4,Da7o,aNK,2oS}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I tried formatting the code properly to see if that'd help but I still have no idea what you're code is supposed to do or what error message or other failure you're getting or what your question is. Please try to clarify your question and provide a real [mcve]. See [ask] if that's not clear.

Comment: So you want a parameterized version of `mkdir -p LUl/{Kyh,NQ,NU,Hjn,lS,TEW}/{Rbf,DU,N4,Da7o,aNK,2oS}`?

Comment: I found the answer... DIRCMD="printf \"%s\0\" ./\'$FLDIR\'/$FLCHILDREN" then eval "$DIRCMD" | xargs -0 mkdir -p

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer
DIRCMD="printf \"%s\0\" ./\'$FLDIR\'/$FLCHILDREN" then eval "$DIRCMD" | xargs -0 mkdir -p 
somehow without the backlashes it did not work. 
I have no idea why and would be nice to know.